# How to impliment the Click events for multiple buttons in a ListView

Tags: android

I have an interface designed as a ListView (but I can change if needed). Each row has 2 buttons: MS and DROP.

Clicking on the buttons should affect only the corresponding row. For example, on the last row (where int "3" is displayed), clicking on MS should call function1(rowPosition) and clicking on DROP should call function2(rowPosition).

I have 2 problems:

- Even without any click listener, clicking on any row activate both corresponding buttons. Maybe ListView is not the correct choice for this kind of interface.
- I can't figure out how to implement the Click listener.

[image]

Here is the main code:

```
package com.thomas.calculation.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Memory_listview extends Activity {
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memory_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> singleRow_list;

    MyAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        singleRow_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
            singleRow_list.add(i, Integer.toString(i) );

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return singleRow_list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return singleRow_list.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class MyViewHolder
    {
        TextView myTextView;
        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            myTextView    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View view_single_row = view;
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = null;

        if (view_single_row==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view_single_row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.memory_listview_row, viewGroup, false);
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view_single_row);
            view_single_row.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) view_single_row.getTag();
        }
        String newData = singleRow_list.get(i);
        //This is not working:
        //Button button_MS       = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_MS); //ERROR: findViewById undefined
        //Button button_MS       = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_MS); //ERROR: findViewById undefined
        //Button button_MS       = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_MS); //APP CRASH
        //Button button_MS       = (Button) view_single_row.findViewById(R.id.button_MS); //APP CRASH
        //Button button_MS       = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.button_MS); //APP CRASH

        myViewHolder.myTextView.setText(newData);
        return view_single_row;
    }
}
```

Here is the row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/bgStack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text=""
        style="@style/memory_monitor"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_MS"
            style="@style/memory_tiny"
            android:text="@string/calc_MS" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_del"
            style="@style/memory_tiny"
            android:text="@string/calc_del" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `button_MS` and `button_del` are not `Buttons`. It's `TextView`. and set separate `onClickListener` for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your getView.

```
MyViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override 
public void onClick(View v){
// do for the other button too..
// yout methods here. 
}
});
```

And change the `TextView` to `Button` in your xml